# error java.sql.SQLException: Índice de columna no válido

Tags: java, sql

Hola todos espero puedan ayudarme 
me deberia retornar true

```
package clases;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import java.sql.ResultSet;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import java.sql.*;

public class consultas extends ConexionOracle {

    public boolean  validarIngreso(String usuario, String clave) {
          PreparedStatement stm = null;
          ResultSet rs = null;

        try {
            String CONSULTAS = "SELECT * FROM REGISTRO WHERE ID_NOMBREU= '"+ usuario +"' AND ID_CONTRASEÑA='"+ clave +"'";

        stm = getConnection().prepareStatement(CONSULTAS);
        rs=stm.executeQuery();

        stm.setString(11, usuario);
        stm.setString(12,clave);


            if(rs.next()){
            return true;
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.err.println(" error "+e);
        }finally{
            try {
                if(getConnection()!=null)getConnection().close();
                if(stm !=null) stm.close();
                if(rs !=null) rs.close();

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                System.err.println("error 2"+e);
            }
        }

      return false;


    }


public static void main(String[] args) {
        consultas co = new consultas();
           System.out.println(co.validarIngreso("LUISA", "LUISA"));}
```

> run: false  error java.sql.SQLException: Índice de columna no válido
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 24 seconds)

Comment: ¿En qué línea te da el error?

Comment: El problema es que intentas definir el valor de parámetros a tu consulta (stm.setString(11, usuario);) y en la definición de esta no hay declaración de parámetros.

Answer (score 2):

El String de CONSULTAS debería más bien ser así:

```
String CONSULTAS = "SELECT * FROM REGISTRO WHERE ID_NOMBREU=? AND ID_CONTRASEÑA=?";
```

Los signos de interrogación son los que se setean en el PreparedStatement. En este caso el índice uno es para el nombre y el dos es para la contraseña.  Entonces, el preparedStatement lo setearía así:

```
    stm = getConnection().prepareStatement(CONSULTAS);

    stm.setString(1, usuario); ///índice 1 para la primera interrogación del preparedStatement
    stm.setString(2,clave); //'indice 2 para la segunda...
```

Una vez seteado el PreparedStatement entonces ejecuto la búsqueda:

```
    rs=stm.executeQuery();
    if(rs.next()){
        return true;
    }
```

Si no quieres usar un PreparedStatement y prefieres usar un Statement, entonces lo haría así:

```
 String CONSULTAS = "SELECT * FROM REGISTRO WHERE ID_NOMBREU= '"+ usuario +"' AND ID_CONTRASEÑA='"+ clave +"'";.
 Statement stmt = getConnection().createStatement();
 rs = Stmt.executeQuery(CONSULTAS);
 if(rs.next()){
      return true;
 }
```

Comment: muchas gracias ya me funciono